# Create new modal dialog on every show()

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, bootstrap-modal

## Reactive modal in Meteor js

Please help me with reactive modal in Meteor js, first I noticed that if I take some value from jQuery selector in modal template I got proper value only on first modal "show()", after first one he gives me same values on every click.
Then I look on code there are many modals with different id like (id="rm-1e7385aa-4ca8-491b-be4e-81baa2afffbc"), probably that cause a problem.
I tried with template preserve but without success.
Can you please help me with this problem?

Code is similar like this,

```
// Reactive Table events
  Template.reactiveTebleList.events({
      'click .reactive-table tbody tr': function (event) {
      var rd_editorder = ReactiveModal.initDialog(rm_EditOrder);
      rd_editorder.show();
     }
 });

   var rm_EditOrder = {
    type: 'type-default',  
    template: Template.tmp_EditOrder, 
     title: "Edit Order",
     removeOnHide: true,
     closable: true,
     buttons: {
          "cancel": {
            class: 'btn-danger',
            label: 'Cancel'
          },
          "ok": {
            closeModalOnClick: true, 
            class: 'btn-info',
            label: 'Back'
          }
      }
    }; 

Template.tmp_EditOrder.events({
'click #saveposition': function(e){

      var selectedPosition = $('#selectPosition').find(":selected").text();
      console.log("selectedPosition: " + selectedPosition);

      rm_EditOrder.hide();
},


<template name="tmp_EditOrder">
    <select class="form-control" id="selectPosition">
                {{#each position}}
                     <option>{{this}}</option>
                {{/each}}
     </select>
 <button type="submit" id="saveposition" class="btn btn-primary">Save Position</button>
</template>
```

Comment: I just add jQuery selector .in and it works :)
`code`var selectedPosition = $('.in #selectPosition').find(":selected").text();
console.log("selectedPosition: " + selectedPosition);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On every modal close use `$(".modalClass").remove()`; or use a meteor package that handles that process for you. I have been using https://github.com/pahans/reactive-modal . As you can see in the docs for this package the removing of the modal dom is done for you on closing of the modal. NOTICE `removeOnHide` which can also be set to true if you want to preserve the modal's dom.

```
var shareDialogInfo = {
template: Template.appShareDialog,
title: "Share the app",
modalDialogClass: "share-modal-dialog", //optional
modalBodyClass: "share-modal-body", //optional
modalFooterClass: "share-modal-footer",//optional
removeOnHide: true, //optional. If this is true, modal will be removed from DOM upon hiding
```